# Notation of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I am really confused about capitalization of variable names in statistics.
When should a random variable be presented by uppercase letter, and when lower case?

For a probability $P(X \leq x)$, what do $x$ and $X$ mean here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to dissociate $x$ from $X$ in your mind—sometimes it matters that they are "the same letter" but in general this is not the case. They are two different characters and they mean two different things and just because they have the same name when read out loud doesn't mean anything.

By convention, a lot of the time we give random variables names which are capital letters from around the end of the alphabet. That doesn't have to be the case—it's arbitrary—but it's a convention. So just as an example here, let's let $X$ be the random variable which represents the outcome of a single roll of a die, so that $X$ takes on values in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Now I believe you understand what would be meant by something like $P(X\leq 2)$: it's the probability that the die comes up either a 1 or a 2. Similarly, we could evaluate numbers for $P(X\leq 4)$, $P(X\leq 6)$, $P(X\leq \pi)$, $P(X\leq 10000)$, $P(X\leq -230)$ or $P(X\leq \text{any real number that you can think of})$. Another way to say this is that $P(X\leq\text{[blank]})$ is a function of a real variable: we can put any number into [blank] that we want and we end up with a unique number. Now a very common symbol for denoting a real variable is $x$, so we can write this function as $P(X\leq x)$. In this expression, $X$ is fixed, and $x$ is allowed to vary over all real numbers.

It's not super significant that $x$ and $X$ are the same letter here. We can similarly write $P(y\leq X)$ and this would be the same function. Where it really starts to come in handy that $x$ and $X$ are the same letter is when you are dealing with things like joint distributions where you have more than one random variable, and you are interested in the probability of for instance $P(X\leq \text{[some number] and } Y\leq\text{[some other number]})$ which can be written more succinctly as $P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$. Then, just to account for the fact that it's hard to keep track of a lot of symbols at the same time, it's convenient that $x$ corresponds to $X$ in an obvious way.

By the way, for a random variable $X$, the function $P(X\leq x)$ a very important function. It is called the [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and is usually denoted by $F_X$, so that $$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$$

Comment: clear and mechanical non abstract explanations like this are very rare +1

Comment: So for $P(X \leq x)$, both $X$ and $x$ are random variables? While meaning is clear, what to call what becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @ParthibanRajendran, no, $X$ is a random variable, but $x$ is a "real variable".

Answer (score 4):

When one writes $P(X\leqslant x)$, one usually means that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable and $x$ a real number, so that $P(X\leqslant x)=P(A)$ where 
$$
A=\{X\leqslant x\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leqslant x\}=X^{-1}((-\infty,x]).
$$

Comment: Can you always find inverse of $X$ so that you can use $X^{−1}((−∞,x])$ in your explanation?

Comment: @Trismegistos One does not require that $X$ has an inverse. Quite generally, $X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}$, as already explained in the answer.

Comment: @Trismegistos in this context $X^-1(S)$ refers to the [preimage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of $X$, which always exists.

Comment: $+1$ for the (partial) explanation of this notation for dealing with random variables. Is there an easily-described formal translation for more general expressions involving (potentially multiple) random variables?

Comment: @dfeuer Such as?

Comment: Well, for example, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables on the same space, we want $XY$ to stand for $a\mapsto X(a)Y(a)$.

Comment: @dfeuer We "want" it and this is what we get: $XY$ does stand for the mapping $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)Y(\omega)$, and this has nothing to do with probability. What are you asking?

Comment: It's intuitively clear to me how to translate this notation in any given context, but not so clear how to do so in general. But I guess it's not that important.

Comment: This explains what I was confused about when I first learned that random variables are functions. I thought, "How can we write $P(X\le x)$ if $X$ is a function and $x$ is a real number?"  It seems like we think of $X$ as both a function and an element of its codomain.  I think that ambiguity would be cleared up if we wrote $P(X(\omega)\le x)$ instead of $P(X\le x)$. It seems common in probability to write things like "$X=$ the number of heads in 10 flips of a fair coin" when we don't want $X$ to be a number, but rather "$X(\omega)=$ the number of heads in the 10 coin flips $\omega$."

Answer (score 4):

$P(X\leq x)$ means the probability that the random variable $X$ is less than or equal to the realization $x$. The lower case $x$ is a fixed constant, whereas $X$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

An uppercase letter is usually for a random variables which is a *function on events* with a real number as its *return value*. A lowercase letter is for a realization of a random variable, which is a value. So $P(X<x)$ means the probability that the *range* of the function $X$ is less than the value $x$.